# Laravel 5.5 form validation with VueJs2

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am just wondering if you had a similar problem as me. Hope you can help me out.

I ve got a form inside vue component:

```
<form>
(vuecomponent :errors="{{$errors}}")</form>
```

Its returning array with forms errors:

```
errors:Array[2]
0:"The price field is required."
1:"The product field is required."
```

My quiestion is how to decide which error msg goes to which input field inside vue component.

The array may vary depends on how many errors we ve got back. I cant use this:

```
this.errors[0] go to 1st input etc
```

Any ideas ?